# tidymodels: "following required column is missing from `new_data` in step..."

Tags: predict, tidymodels, recipe

I'm creating and fitting a workflow for a lasso regression model in {tidymodels}.  The model fits fine, but when I go to predict the test set I get an error saying "the following required column is missing from `new_data`". Tha column ("price") is in both the train and test sets.  Is this a bug?  What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```r
# split the data (target variable in house_sales_df is "price")
split <- initial_split(house_sales_df, prop = 0.8)
train <- split %>% training()
test <-  split %>% testing()

# create and fit workflow
lasso_prep_recipe <-
  recipe(price ~ ., data = train) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric())

lasso_model <- 
  linear_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet")

lasso_workflow <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(lasso_prep_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(lasso_model)

lasso_fit <- lasso_workflow %>% 
  fit(data = train)

# predict test set
predict(lasso_fit, new_data = test)
```

`predict()` results in this error:

```
Error in `step_normalize()`:
! The following required column is missing from `new_data` in step 'normalize_MXQEf': price.
Backtrace:
  1. stats::predict(lasso_fit, new_data = test, type = "numeric")
  2. workflows:::predict.workflow(lasso_fit, new_data = test, type = "numeric")
  3. workflows:::forge_predictors(new_data, workflow)
  5. hardhat:::forge.data.frame(new_data, blueprint = mold$blueprint)
  7. hardhat:::run_forge.default_recipe_blueprint(...)
  8. hardhat:::forge_recipe_default_process(...)
 10. recipes:::bake.recipe(object = rec, new_data = new_data)
 12. recipes:::bake.step_normalize(step, new_data = new_data)
 13. recipes::check_new_data(names(object$means), object, new_data)
 14. cli::cli_abort(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error because `all_numeric()` in `step_normalize()` selects the outcome `price` which isn't avaliable at predict time. Use `all_numeric_predictors()` and you should be good

```r
# split the data (target variable in house_sales_df is "price")
split <- initial_split(house_sales_df, prop = 0.8)
train <- split %>% training()
test <-  split %>% testing()

# create and fit workflow
lasso_prep_recipe <-
  recipe(price ~ ., data = train) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

lasso_model <- 
  linear_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) %>% 
  set_engine("glmnet")

lasso_workflow <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(lasso_prep_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(lasso_model)

lasso_fit <- lasso_workflow %>% 
  fit(data = train)

# predict test set
predict(lasso_fit, new_data = test)
```

Comment: Thanks, @EmilHvitfeldt. That eliminates the error. But I also want to normalize the target variable `price`.  Do you know how I do that at predict time? Lasso regression doesn't work right if it's not normalized, the penalty doesn't seem to be applied. Coefficients aren't forced to zero.

Comment: Never mind, @EmilHvitfeldt. I figured it out.  My penalty value had to be much larger -- like several orders of magnitude larger.