# log transform outcome variable in tidymodels workflow

Tags: r, tidymodels

I'm having a hard time getting a tidymodels workflow to make new predictions. Specifically, I want to log transform my outcome variable as part of the workflow, but when it comes time to predict new observations this piece of the workflow breaks.

```
# recipe
trans_rec <- 
    recipe(Transactions ~ ., data = train.data) %>% 
      update_role(Event.ID, Opponent, new_role = "ID") %>%
      step_date(Calendar.Date, features = c("dow",'month','year'),keep_original_cols = FALSE) %>% 
      step_log(Transactions,Total.Attendance)


# model
glm_spec <- linear_reg(penalty = tune()) %>%
  set_engine(engine = 'glmnet')

param_grid <- grid_regular(penalty(),levels = 100)
  
wf <- add_recipe(workflow(), trans_rec)
  
mod_res <- 
    tune_grid(
      wf %>%
      add_model(glm_spec),
      resamples = train.folds,
      grid = tibble(penalty = seq(0.0,0.1,0.01)),
      metrics = metric_set(rmse,rsq),
      control = control_grid(save_pred=TRUE)
    )

# finalizing workflow
final_mdl <- finalize_workflow(wf %>% add_model(glm_spec),final_lass)


# fit on full train data
fit_mod <- fit(final_mdl, train.data)

# test data predictions
predictions <- predict(fit_mod, test.data)
```

I get this error though when I try this last part.

```
The following required column is missing from `new_data` in step 'log_1P9bM': Transactions.
```

Now, I've seen something similar on stack to this problem, but the OP just ended up not scaling their outcome [tidymodels: "following required column is missing from `new_data` in step..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74215751/tidymodels-following-required-column-is-missing-from-new-data-in-step). I dont want to do that, and in fact **need** to log transform this variable.  Please let me know what i can do to incorporate an outcome log transformation in my workflow such that i can make future predictions with this process!

Answer (score 2):

For log transformations to the outcome, we strongly recommend that those transformation be done before you pass them to the `recipe()`. This is because you are not guaranteed to have an outcome when predicting on new data. And the recipe fails.

Since log transformations isn't a learned transformation you can safely do it before.

```r
train.data$Transactions <- log(train.data$Transactions)

if (!is.null(test.data$Transactions)) {
  test.data$Transactions <- log(test.data$Transactions)
}
```

Comment: What about if the outcome variable needs to be scaled? If using CV this would need to occur within the folds no?  Another odd behavior is that last_fit works when I have my outcome in the recipe. Why would it work there but not when fitting and predicting separately?

Comment: I think I answered my question on my own relating to the second part. But am still confused about the scaling part. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In general, I don't see much need to scale outcomes. And if you have static non-learned transformation such as log or sqrt, you can safely apply it before the splitting.

recipes design tries to stop the user from making common mistakes such as data leakage and overfitting. Another such mistake is generally to modify the outcome as part of preprocessing. It doesn't look bad right now. But when you try to predict with your model on truly new data. It will error because you are trying to modify an outcome that by definition is unknown

Comment: I don't see it as problematic to pre-scale your outcome as an initial first step. Pre-processing is about the predictors, not the dependent variable(s). There are, of course, exceptions (Like the Box-Cox transform), but all of the analysis is conditional on the scale/units of the outcome.