# broom::augment errors with recipes::step_log

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I am trying to use the `tidymodels` framework to predict `outcome` based on `predictor`.  I want to use `log(outcome) ~ predictor` as my model, but `outcome` has zeroes.  Therefore, I use `recipes::step_log(outcome, offset = 0.0001)`.  However, `broom::augment()` fails on that step.  How can I accomplish this?

```r
df <- 
  data.frame(
    outcome = c(0,1,3,6,0,7,3,5,6,7),
    predictor = 1:10
  )

rec <-
  df |> 
  recipes::recipe(outcome ~ predictor) |>
  recipes::step_log(outcome, offset = 0.0001)

wf <-
  workflows::workflow(
    rec,
    parsnip::linear_reg()
  )  

fit_model <- parsnip::fit(wf, df)

broom::augment(
  fit_model,
  new_data = df
)
#> Error in `step_log()`:
#> ! The following required column is missing from `new_data` in step
#>   'log_gBnGL': outcome.

#> Backtrace:
#>      x
#>   1. +-broom::augment(fit_model, new_data = df)
#>   2. \-workflows:::augment.workflow(fit_model, new_data = df)
#>   3.   \-workflows:::forge_predictors(new_data, x)
#>   4.     +-hardhat::forge(new_data, blueprint = mold$blueprint)
#>   5.     \-hardhat:::forge.data.frame(new_data, blueprint = mold$blueprint)
#>   6.       +-hardhat::run_forge(blueprint, new_data = new_data, outcomes = outcomes)
#>   7.       \-hardhat:::run_forge.default_recipe_blueprint(...)
#>   8.         \-hardhat:::forge_recipe_default_process(...)
#>   9.           +-recipes::bake(object = rec, new_data = new_data)
#>  10.           \-recipes:::bake.recipe(object = rec, new_data = new_data)
#>  11.             +-recipes::bake(step, new_data = new_data)
#>  12.             \-recipes:::bake.step_log(step, new_data = new_data)
#>  13.               \-recipes::check_new_data(names(object$columns), object, new_data)
#>  14.                 \-cli::cli_abort(...)
#>  15.                   \-rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The recipe (incl. `step_log`) operates on the *predictors* (try `recipes::step_log(predictor, offset = 0.0001)`). To transform the outcome, you can pipe the result of `augment` into `dplyr::mutate(log_outcome = log(outcome + 1e-4))`

Comment: @I_O, do you mean pipe data with a log-transformed `outcome` into `augment()`?  As I understand it, one of the main advantages of `recipes` is the ability to not have to transform new data to make predictions.  As long as it always comes in the same format, `recipes` takes care of that for me.  Is there a way to do it without having to transform `outcome` by hand?

Comment: @I_O, also, looking at the documentation (https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/has_role.html), I don't see why you say that a recipe only operates on predictors.  Doesn't the existence of the `all_outcomes()` helper function imply that a recipe can operate on outcomes as well?

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question - sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to [log transform outcome variable in tidymodels workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158409/log-transform-outcome-variable-in-tidymodels-workflow/76158558#76158558)

For log transformations to the outcome, we strongly recommend that those transformation be done before you pass them to the `recipe()`. This is because you are not guaranteed to have an outcome when predicting (which is what happens when you `augment()` a workflow) on new data. And the recipe fails.

You are seeing this here as when you predict on a `workflow()` object, it only passes the predictors, as it is all that it needs. Hence why you see this error.

Since log transformations isn't a learned transformation you can safely do it before.

```r
train_data$outcome <- log(train_data$outcome)

if (!is.null(test.data$outcome)) {
  test_data$outcome <- log(test_data$outcome)
}
```

As for the existence of `all_outcomes()`. {recipes} is written to quite flexible in the operations it can do. So modifying outcomes isn't a problem. However, {workflows} is not as flexible as it is trying to guard you against common mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  One thing I don’t understand is why the recipe would allow it but not the workflow.  When would I ever use a recipe without a workflow?

Comment: {recipes} is written to be used within {workflows} but isn't restricted to. If you find that your pipeline can use {recipes} with {workflows} then it won't stop you. I sometimes use recipes alone especially for dimensionality reduction methods like pca and umap