# Problem when scoring new data -- tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels

I'm learning tidymodels. The following code runs nicely:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

# Draw a random sample of 2000 to try the models

set.seed(1234)

diamonds <- diamonds %>%    
  sample_n(2000)
  
diamonds_split <- initial_split(diamonds, prop = 0.80, strata="price")

diamonds_train <- training(diamonds_split)
diamonds_test <- testing(diamonds_split)

folds <- rsample::vfold_cv(diamonds_train, v = 10, strata="price")

metric <- metric_set(rmse,rsq,mae)

# Model KNN 

knn_spec <-
  nearest_neighbor(
    mode = "regression", 
    neighbors = tune("k"),
    engine = "kknn"
  ) 

knn_rec <-
  recipe(price ~ ., data = diamonds_train) %>%
  step_log(all_outcomes()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())

knn_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(knn_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(knn_rec)

knn_grid = expand.grid(k=c(1,5,10,30))

knn_res <- 
  tune_grid(
    knn_wflow,
    resamples = folds,
    metrics = metric,
    grid = knn_grid
  )

collect_metrics(knn_res)
autoplot(knn_res)

show_best(knn_res,metric="rmse")

# Best KNN 

best_knn_spec <-
  nearest_neighbor(
    mode = "regression", 
    neighbors = 10,
    engine = "kknn"
  ) 

best_knn_wflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(best_knn_spec) %>%
  add_recipe(knn_rec)

best_knn_fit <- last_fit(best_knn_wflow, diamonds_split)

collect_metrics(best_knn_fit)
```

But when I try to fit the best model on the training set and applying it to the test set I run into problems. The following two lines give me the error : "Error in `step_log()`:
! The following required column is missing from `new_data` in step 'log_mUSAb': price.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred."

```
# Predict Manually

f1 = fit(best_knn_wflow,diamonds_train)
p1 = predict(f1,new_data=diamonds_test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is related to [log transform outcome variable in tidymodels workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158409/log-transform-outcome-variable-in-tidymodels-workflow/76158558#76158558)

For log transformations to the outcome, we strongly recommend that those transformation be done before you pass them to the `recipe()`. This is because you are not guaranteed to have an outcome when predicting (which is what happens when you `last_fit()` a workflow) on new data. And the recipe fails.

You are seeing this here as when you predict on a `workflow()` object, it only passes the predictors, as it is all that it needs. Hence why you see this error.

Since log transformations isn't a learned transformation you can safely do it before.

```r
diamonds_train$price <- log(diamonds_train$price)

if (!is.null(diamonds_test$price)) {
  diamonds_test$price <- log(diamonds_test$price)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Emil. Makes a lot of sense. I guess it does not make much sense including transformations of the dependent variable in a recipe that will be applied to a truly new dataset (without price). Thanks again.